# Jenkins groovy build job error groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to build a job using groovy and I'm using below script.

build job: 'Test', parameters: [string(name: 'PACKAGE_NAME', value: 'Test'), string(name: 'BUILD_NUM', value: '10')]

But getting below error when I 'm executing the script

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.string() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[name:PACKAGE_NAME, value:Test]].

Could anyone please help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was trying to execute it in script console, later I tried executing the same in build pipeline which resolved the issue.